# SQL regexp with numbers and % character

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to match the following string "50% off" in Oracle db. I've created an SQL query.

```
  select *
     from table1
     where column1 like '%[0-9]+\% off%' ESCAPE '\';
```

This query however does not provide any results. 
Moreover how do I match "50% off" AND "$50 off" with one query?

```
'%[0-9]+\%? off%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The one above does not work either :(

The only query I got working was the following:

```
select *
         from table1
         where column1 like '%\% off%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: If you don't provide any sample data or expected results it's a bit hard for us to tell why any given regex doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#i1034153) operator in Oracle only accepts single-character (`_`) and multi-character (`%`) wildcards and not regular expression.

Instead use the [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#i1048942) condition:

```
SQL>  WITH DATA AS (
  2   SELECT '50% off' txt FROM dual
  3   UNION ALL SELECT '$50 off' txt FROM dual)
  4   SELECT *
  5     FROM DATA
  6    WHERE regexp_like(txt, '([[:digit:]]+%)|(\$[[:digit:]]+) off');

TXT
-------
50% off
$50 off
```

Comment: @APC or I got lucky on the main page refresh =)